# How do I add a COALESCE to a db_select?

Tags: database

I want to achieve the following query using `db_select()`:

```
SELECT 
  Column1, 
  Column2, 
  COALESCE(Column1, Column2) AS Column3 
FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES
```

How do I add the coalesced column to the query?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an expression:

```
$query = db_select('TEST_ATTRIBUTES', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('Column1', 'Column2'));

$query->addExpression('COALESCE(Column1, Column2)', 'Column3');
```

The above yields:

```
SELECT  
  t.Column1 AS Column1, 
  t.Column2 AS Column2, 
  COALESCE(Column1, Column2) AS Column3
FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES t
```

Comment: Hi Clive, now the coalesce is working on one of my queries, I need to put addexpression on a specific query can I add my code on the question to see it ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question, editing a question after it's been answered is very confusing for future visitors! The answer is to use a subquery by the way, try searching for it ("db_select sub query" or similar), and ask a question if you can't find an exact answer

Comment: Yea wright I'm searching for sub query and I'll remove what i've add to the first question

Comment: Please Clive what if I want to use COALESCE on a db_query (not db_select)

Comment: `db_query` runs raw SQL, so you just literally write it as you want it to be executed